# systemd: Failed at step CHDIR spawning /bin/sh: No such file or directory

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to create a systemd service. I see this error message in my journal.

```
Failed at step CHDIR spawning /bin/sh: No such file or directory
```

What causes this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had

```
WorkingDirectory=/tmp/dir
ExecStartPost=/bin/rm /tmp/dir    
ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c "foo bar"
```

One `ExecStartPost` was deleting the working directory. The second `ExecStartPost` couldn't get into that directory to run the command. That's the error that was generated.

Comment: Are you sure it was `/bin/rm /tmp/dir`, and not `rmdir`? `rm` would fail if `/tmp/dir` was a directory.